# highstock strange behavior scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, highcharts

i made a chart, with highstock, that contains the enabled scrollbar but when i focus the mouse on it, it happens a strange behavoir: the chart goes down and covers the scrollbar.
the options that i used are:

```
var options = {
        chart: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            renderTo: 'containerGrafico'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: '',
            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '€ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: seriesMesi,
            labels: {
                 formatter: function () {
                    return arrayMesi[this.value.substring(4, 6)] + " " + this.value.substring(0, 4);
                }
            },
            max: 6
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
            barBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            barBorderRadius: 7,
            barBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
            buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            rifleColor: 'transparent',
            trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
            trackBorderWidth: 1,
            trackBorderColor: 'silver',
            trackBorderRadius: 7
        },
        series: [
                                     {
                                    name: 'Totale Versato',
                                    color: '#96B7D8',
                                    type: 'column'
                                },
                                 {
                                 name: 'Prelievi',
                                 color: '#D1D1D1',
                                 type: 'column'
                             }]
    };
```

anybody can tell me where i'm wrong?
thank you very much
Cinzia

Answer (score 0):

In general, categorized axis for Highstock isn't supported.

Anyway, for me it works properly, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1004/

Try to update to latest (`1.3.10`) version and remove categories. Or use Highcharts with categorized axis.

If none of above will help - recreate issue on jsFiddle.